# str_replace PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace certain characters with some other strings
I got it to work on my main page with this exact code but on another page it wont work.

In the database i Got this `±1¢2£¥3§4£` as `description2`
In my php i use

```
$description2 = mysql_result($product, 0, 'productDescription2');

if ($description2 !=""){
$searchArray = array('±', '¢', '£', '¥', '§');
$replaceArray = array('x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x');
$teknisk =  str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $description2);}
```

And as the output i use `echo ''. $teknisk .'';`

But the result is this `�1�2��3�4�` (The same as the original `description2`)

instead of `x1x2xx3x4x`

Please help!

Comment: I think it's due to encoding in your database. I tried your script and it works when `$description2 = "±1¢2£¥3§4£"`

Comment: you can change the character set & collation of your database by either using phpMyAdmin or via this sql (backup first):    ALTER TABLE _yourtable_ CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: Could you please echo this command here. 
`show variables like 'character%';`

Comment: AljoshaBre
`character_set_client  utf8

character_set_connection  utf8

character_set_database  latin1

character_set_filesystem  binary

character_set_results  utf8

character_set_server  latin1

character_set_system  utf8

character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/`

Comment: You should probably change your database charset. 
`use YOURDB;` 
`alter database YOURDB default charset UTF8;`

Comment: I did this aswell but no luck there either.
But as i wrote in my frist post I have used this exact script with the samedatabase in another .php file.
So i reckon the problem is in the php file.

Comment: Yes, well - maybe. If you're on linux, this command will change encoding of your .php file: `vim yourfile.php -c ":set bomb" -c ":set fileencoding=utf-8" -c ":wq"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think since you have some weird characters they might go beyond ascii range and you might need to use multibyte string functions, though it does not have str_replace analogue, you might need to use multibyte regexes.

Comment: It was the wierd signs that made it not work.
So i changed them to another set of characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps database uses different encoding than your PHP file. Start with comparing those strings converted with `bin2hex()` function (in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Second attempt:

There are a bunch of suggestions in the PHP doc's comments.  Try these:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php#106653
2. http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php#75566
3. http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php#72344

---

Try explicitly setting your page's chartype.  Try placing this in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Or, if you're using HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score -1):

please take a look at this , it will tell you how to handle UTF characters in a web app

[UTF-8 in Web Apps](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)